# Azure mobile service javascript back end how to set and read cookies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, cookies, azure-mobile-services

So I have this azure mobile service with node back end but I would need to store a cookie when a specific api has been called.

I have my login api set up and working correctly and all I want now is to set a cookie, but I cannot find anything from the azure documentation regarding cookies.

So basically how can I store a cookie from azure javascript back end and how can I access it later from table operations script etc. to check its validity?

EDIT: I checked the `Express` api reference, which azure says that its request and response objects are from. But even when using `response.cookie('token', 'value', {maxAge: 3600000})` I still cannot access it from the request object on the other api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you don't have access to the HTTP request headers (including cookies) from within table scripts (you should be able to access them in custom APIs). If you feel that this is a valuable feature, please add a new feature request at http://feedback.azure.com/forums/216254-mobile-services.

Comment: can you give an example of how to set the cookie or a reference to some online link/documentation?